# MAPI Linking Static Library (LNK2019: Unresolved External Symbol)

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, mapi

I try to make use of Microsoft's MAPI (Extended MAPI) using Visual Studio 2017.

So first I created a solution with 3 projects:

1. Visual C++ - Windows Desktop - Static Library
2. Visual C++ - CLR - Class Library
3. Visual C# - Classic Windows Desktop - WPF-App

## (1) is set up as follows:

#### stdafx.h

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

// Not auto generated
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
```

#### InstanceManager.h

```
#pragma once

namespace NativeWrapper
{
    class DLLEXPORT InstanceManager
    {
    public:
        InstanceManager();
        int Init();
        void UnInit();
        ~InstanceManager();
    private:
        bool _Initialized;
    };
}
```

#### InstanceManager.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "InstanceManager.h"

namespace NativeWrapper
{
    InstanceManager::InstanceManager()
    {
        _Initialized = false;
    }

    int InstanceManager::Init()
    {
        if (!_Initialized)
        {
            MAPIINIT init = {
                MAPI_INIT_VERSION,
                MAPI_MULTITHREAD_NOTIFICATIONS
            };
            return MAPIInitialize(&init);
        }
    }

    void InstanceManager::UnInit()
    {
        if (_Initialized)
        {
            MAPIUninitialize();
        }
    }

    InstanceManager::~InstanceManager()
    {
        UnInit();
    }
}
```

I also downloaded the required headers for MAPI Development and referenced
them by adding the corresponding path (`C:\Office 2010 Developer Resources\Outlook 2010 MAPI Headers`) to the additional include directories.

## (2) is setup as follows:

#### InstanceManager.h

```
#pragma once

#include "..\StaticLib1\NativeInstanceManager.h"

namespace MAPIManaged
{
    ref class InstanceManager
    {
    public:
        InstanceManager();
        ~InstanceManager();
        int Init();
        void UnInit();
    private:
        NativeWrapper::InstanceManager* _NativeObject;
    };
}
```

#### InstanceManager.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "InstanceManager.h"    

namespace MAPIManaged
{
    InstanceManager::InstanceManager()
    {
        _NativeObject = new NativeWrapper::InstanceManager();
    }

    InstanceManager::~InstanceManager()
    {
        delete _NativeObject;
    }

    int InstanceManager::Init()
    {
        return _NativeObject->Init();
    }

    void InstanceManager::UnInit()
    {
        _NativeObject->UnInit();
    }
}
```

Also there is a Project-Reference on (1).
I did it by Right-Clicking the Project 2 and added Project 1.

## (3) is set up as follows:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

           var obj = new MAPIManaged.InstanceManager();
           obj.Init();
        }
    }
}
```

Also there is a Project-Reference on (2).
I did it by Right-Clicking the Project 3 and added Project 2.

## Error

Although I referenced the Static Library I get the following errors:

#### Error 1: MapUninitialize Linking Error

```
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "_MAPIUninitialize@0"
    in function ""public: void __thiscall NativeWrapper::InstanceManager::UnInit(void)" (?UnInit@InstanceManager@NativeWrapper@@QAEXXZ)".
ClassLibrary1   PATH\WrapNative\ClassLibrary1\StaticLib1.lib(InstanceManager.obj)   1
```

#### Error 2: MapInitialize Linking Error

```
    Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "_MAPIInitialize@4"
in function ""public: int __thiscall NativeWrapper::InstanceManager::Init(void)" (?Init@InstanceManager@NativeWrapper@@QAEHXZ)".
ClassLibrary1   PATH\WrapNative\ClassLibrary1\StaticLib1.lib(InstanceManager.obj)   1
```

Comment: Looks like you simply forgot to link mapi32.lib.  Put #pragma comment(lib, "mapi32.lib") somewhere or add the link dependency.

Comment: Wow ... I struggled hours on finding solution.
Edit: I want to mark that as an answer but I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never statically link to any MAPI functions - you must first find the right MAPI dll and use LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress.

Look at the [MFCMAPI source code](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) for an example on how this is done.

Comment: [citation required]

Comment: If you insist, some official documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc963763.aspx

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19427146)

Comment: @miken32 - it does provide an answer. the answer is not to use a lib file to link to any MAPI functions. The functions must be defined as pointers to functions in the source files (h or cpp) and initialized using LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19427146)

Comment: @kilojoules - the essential part is there: don't statically link. *How* you do that is not important.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko could you please tell me why that is important to not to link statically to any MAPI functions? Is it a practice that is applied in other scenarios also?

Comment: Because msmapi32.dll might not be on PATH, so Windows would not be able to correctly resolve the static link to the dll. Plus the name of the dll can be different - msmapi32.dll for most versions of Outlook, exmapi32.dll for the standalone version of MAPI, mmgaclient.dll for the Centennial (Windows Store) version of Outlook, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Dmitry's answer - the only version of mapi32.lib out there is buggy (missing exports, wrong number and types of parameters, etc.) and unsupported by Microsoft for over a decade. The MSDN article [Link to MAPI functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/how-to-link-to-mapi-functions) discusses this in depth and offers a number of options for linking to MAPI, all of which boil down to:
1 - Locate the correct MAPI DLL to load, which is non-trivial, involving calls to  [FGetComponentPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/fgetcomponentpath) to locate the proper implementation of MAPI. In practice, you can simplify this step a bit by just linking to the system mapi32.dll (itself a stub), but you will miss out on exports offered by Outlook's MAPI which are not exposed in the system stub.
2 - Once located, use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to link to the exports.

This article also links to the Microsoft recommended [MAPIStubLibrary](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/MAPIStubLibrary), which encapsulates the logic described above. It is preferred that this stub library be used instead of hand rolling location and linking logic.

Disclaimer: I am a Microsoft employee, author of [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi), and co-author of the MAPI Stub Library along with the Outlook development team.